# Как правильно сделать запрос GET к API https://email-format.com/i/api_v2/ при помощи axios.get

Tags: node.js

Н странице https://email-format.com/i/api_v2/ нету примеров. У меня есть ключ, какой должен быть синтаксис запроса ?

```
   const getEmail = async (firstName, lastName, company) => {
      const param = {
        Authorization: "xxxxxxxyyyyzzzz",
        domain: company,
        first_name: firstName,
        last_name: lastName
      }
      const res = await axios.get(API, {headers: param})
      return res.data
```

console.log(getEmail(name, surname, company)) не работает.
При запуске node xxx.js пишет: Promise {  } и выскакивает обратно в командную строку.

Answer (score 2):

async возвращает promise

```
const getEmail = async (firstName, lastName, company) => {
  const param = {
    Authorization: "xxxxxxxyyyyzzzz",
    domain: company,
    first_name: firstName,
    last_name: lastName
  }
  const res = await axios.get(API, {headers: param})
  return await res.json(); 
}

getEmail(name, surname, company).then(res=>{
    console.log(res.data);
}).catch(err=>console.log(err));
```